# Can you suggest a algorithm that'll mark the points which belong to a cylinder?

Tags: math, geometry, polar-coordinates, cartesian-coordinates

We have a 3d point cloud where there are some cylindrical shapes. We can pro-grammatically access each of the point's (x, y, z) coordinate.

Comment: What do you know about the cylinder? Is the cylinder's axis necessarily parallel to the z axis? Are you trying to tweak/adjust the cylinder to cover some large number of points?

Comment: I am trying to access each points from any of (x, y, z) coordinate  where every points which belong to a cylinder @Danial

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [RANSAC](http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/Conferences/7521/cylinder_5_points_computation.pdf) algorithm. In the Wikipedia page there is an example for a 2D point cloud and a line. Extending it to 3D and a cylinder is easy.

Basically, you randomly choose minimal subsets from the point cloud that fully determine a cylinder, you create a mathematical model of the cylinder and then you look at how many points confirm this hypotesis (e.g. they are not further from the modelled cylinder than some threshold) and you keep the best cylinder so far. You do that some number of times.

For a cylinder you need, <strike>I think, 4</strike> 5 points to get its radius and the main axis vector. Then you might need another points to determine a height of the cylinder, if it is your case.

There is an article that deals with determining cylindric equations from five points: [Cylinders Through Five Points: Computational Algebra and
Geometry](http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/Conferences/7521/cylinder_5_points_computation.pdf). It also has *Mathematica* code in the appendix and loads of references to other articles.

Comment: @zagkljan can you plz make me clear about mathematical model of the cylinder.....???
thnx in advance

Comment: @AbdurRazzak I added a reference to an article that might give you the answers.

Answer (score 0):

Check if z is within `[minz..maxz]`

```
if (z > maxz || z < minz)
  return false;
```

Then see if the point is inside the circle of center `(centerX,centerY)` and radious `R`:

```
return ((x-centerX)*(x-centerX) + (y-centerY)*(y-centerY) <= R*R);
```

this assumes the cylinder is not rotated

Comment: @Exception i am little bit confused about this line " point is inside the circle of center (centerX,centerY) " can u plz explain it again clearly. 

thnx in advance

Comment: @AbdurRazzak a circle has equation (x-xc)^2 + (y-yc)^2 = r^2, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circle#Equations . thus in your case once you have checked that z is ok, you just have to check if (x,y) is a point for which (x-xc)^2 + (y-yc)^2 <= r^2

Answer (score 0):

Outlining a solution: (*We have used similar solution in the past, but I lost the details*)

You will basically need to find  **center (C)**, **axis (n)** (*direction cosines*) and **radius (r)** for a cylinder.

Then for each point **P**, deviation (or error) from desired cylinder and a point is (*calculating normal distance between point and the axis*).

`delta^2 = |(P -C) - (P - C) . n * n|^2 - r^2`

We need to minimize the error. By using partial differentiation, and eigven vectors, we can find out values corresponding to minimum error. It is also possible to sample the points (if we know that they belong to same surface).